# prove existence + compute $\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} \frac{e^{xy} - 1}{y}$ - is my proof correct?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

$\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} \frac{e^{xy} - 1}{y}$

i'm substituting $t := e^x, u := e^y$, then the limit looks like this:
$\lim_{(t, u) \to (1, 1)} \frac{tu - 1}{\ln u}$

i believe that's acceptable, because even though $\ln u$ is only defined for $u>0$, it is defined in small enough neighbourhoods of 1. does that make sense?

i'm squeezing the transformed limit, using $|\ln u| < u$ for $u > 0.5$, again limiting the validity of my squeezing functions (with the same argument).

$o \leq |\frac{tu - 1}{\ln u}| = \frac{|tu - 1|}{|\ln u|} \leq \frac{|tu - 1|}{u}$

and since both, lower and upper limit, converge to 0 for $(t, u) \to (1, 1)$, so will the middle one.

would that be an acceptable proof? if not, what would be better?

thanks!

Comment: $tu$  is  not $e^{xy}$, its $e^{x+y}$

Comment: @vlkr if $|\ln u| < u$ then $\frac{|tu-1|}{|\ln u|} \ge \frac{|tu-1}{u}$, not the other way round.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your substitution is not correct, since $tu=e^{x+y}\neq e^{xy}.$

Since $\displaystyle \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{e^t-1}{t}=1$, there is some $\delta>0$
such that for all $t$ s.t. $0<|t|<\delta$ we get $$\left|\frac{e^t-1}{t}-1\right|<1 \rightarrow \left|\frac{e^t-1}{t}\right|<2.$$
Since $\frac{e^{xy}-1}{y}=0$ for $x=0$ and for $x\neq 0$ such that $0<|x|,\,|y|<\sqrt{\delta}$ (and therefore $|xy|<\delta$) we get:

$$\left|\frac{e^{xy}-1}{y}\right|=\left|\frac{e^{xy}-1}{xy}\right|\,|x|=\left|\frac{e^t-1}{t}\right|\,|x|<2|x|.$$

All in all, for $x,\,y$ such that $y\neq 0$ (since $\frac{e^{xy}-1}{y}$ is undefined for $y=0$) and $x$ satisfy $|x|<\sqrt{\delta}$ and $0<|y|<\sqrt{\delta}$, we get:

$$\left|\frac{e^{xy}-1}{y}\right|<2|x|\to 0$$
as $x$ tends to $0$. From the squeeze thereom you get that the limit exists and is equal to $0$.

Answer (score 2):

A better proof: $\frac {e^{t}-1} t \to 1$ as $ t \to 0$ so (multiplying numerator and denominator by $y$) the given limit is $(1)(\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} y) =0$.